# Faster RSA library than the one used in jCryption?

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, jcryption

Is there a faster RSA algorithm than the one used in jCryption (http://www.jcryption.org/)?
I only need the decryption part of the library, if that helps. Also my RSA keys are in integer format, and the cipertext is in HEX format. The reason why i want a faster library, is that the one i've already got, spends a whopping 3.4 seconds to do the decryption. I'm using PHP.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not only want a faster, but also a *secure* implementation of RSA in PHP: [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)'s Crypt_RSA is what you want if you absolutely must be doing RSA in PHP, since it implements OAEP (jCryption only implements plain, insecure textbook RSA which is not [semantically secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security) and vulnerable to a number of [cryptanalytical attacks](http://www.comms.engg.sussex.ac.uk/fft/crypto/Why_Textbook_ElGamal_and_RSA_Encryption_are_Insecure.pdf)).

But chances are, that if you are rolling your own cryptosystem using RSA in PHP, you are doing something wrong in the first place...